# Screw Size Unit Conversion

Tags: screws

I would like to find out what English units of measure are for a screw size described as ST5X70.  Where can I get this information?

Answer (score 6):

That would be a self tapping screw with a diameter of 5 mm, and a length of 70 mm.  In English units it would be a self tapping screw with a diameter between 3/16" and 13/64" (0.1969"), and a length of 2 3/4".